# Getting information about a class with NSLog

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, class, object, nslog

When I first started learning XCode I remember hearing something about how it has cool features to inspect an object and get information about its class. Now I need to use these cool features. How can I use NSLog to get class information about an object and other cool information about an object.

Comment: What kind of information are you looking for? Intrinsically, "cool features" mean nothing, unless you have something specific in mind.

Comment: For one thing, I want to know what class an object is, and what methods it responds to.

Answer (score 2):

You should use the [XCode Debugger](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/iphone_development/130-Debugging_Applications/debugging_applications.html)! NSLog isn't meant for such tasks.

If you're a registered Apple Developer there're several free [WWDC 2010 Videos](http://tuvix.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2010/) that gives you a pretty good introduction into iPhone App Debugging.

And for your information: Apple **doesn't** allow any NSLog Output in App Store (Production) Apps.